# all bar should be of same height . data part should be coloured and rest should be grayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

**I want bar like thermometer .All bar in a bar chart should be of same height .  Data part should be blue coloured and rest should be grayed.**. Now it is of different height and only blue coloured .
can someone help me out on this.

all bar should be of same height . data part should be coloured and rest should be grayed.
all bar should be of same height . data part should be coloured and rest should be grayed.
all bar should be of same height . data part should be coloured and rest should be grayed.
all bar should be of same height . data part should be coloured and rest should be grayed.
all bar should be of same height . data part should be coloured and rest should be grayed.
all bar should be of same height . data part should be coloured and rest should be grayed.
all bar should be of same height . data part should be coloured and rest should be grayed.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 200]
    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
    height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
       
    </p>
</figure>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsdAl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there ,  just need to add a dummy series and link it to main series.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_population">Wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Population (millions)',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        series: {
          grouping: false
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 80,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor:
            Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#FFFFFF',
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            data: [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000],
            enableMouseTracking : false,
            linkedTo: "main",
            color: "#e8f1f8",
        
        },{
        id: "main",
        name: 'Year 1800',
        data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 200]
    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
    height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
       
    </p>
</figure>
```

Comment: Now it is showing 2-2 series for each bar. But originaly it was only one series. Which is wrong because on hovering on grayed part it showing data but that should not be there . Because that does not represent data . I want my bar to be like thermometer.

Comment: @ankitdubey you can use enableMouseTracking : false property  for the  dummy series to disable tooltip on hover.have updated the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plotBands` to add the gray element, example:

```
    xAxis: {
        ...,
        plotBands: [{
            from: -0.25,
            to: 0.25,
            color: 'gray'
        }]
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j1fcerq5/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands

Comment: how to make it work for all categories . Now it is only working for one category i.e, "AFRICA"

Comment: how to make it work for all categories . Now it is only working for one category that is "AFRICA"

Comment: Hi @ankit dubey, Just add more plot-bands, you can do that programmatically: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4Lj9s1x8/